# Nashorn failed to call a static method of a 3rd party Java class, any solutions?

Tags: java, scripting, nashorn

The code in Nashorn is to parse a very simple JSON string into a JSONObject (com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject), simply going as:

```
   var jso = Java.type('com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject').parseObject('{"name": "nothing"}');
```

But when ran the Java project, I received below error message:

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Java.type("com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject").parseObject is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
...
```

I tried to `print(Java.type('com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject'))`, and the class is obviously there with output `[JavaClass com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject]`

Anybody knows what's the root cause of this error, and how to fix it?